# how to connect a model which is not full-mapping to data source to a store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a xml data source which contains many nodes, but I am only interested in a few of nodes.

```
<config generated_at="2014-04-17 18:44:44"> <acModes>A,D,O</acModes> <acModeNames A="Arrival" D="Departure" O="All"/> <acShapes B="ac-clone" C="ac-clone" Default="ud-clone" G="tp-clone" H="he-clone" J="ac-clone" M="ud-clone" P="tp-clone" R="ac-clone" T="tp-clone" U="ud-clone" Z="ud-clone"/> <acColours> <Unknown number="0"> <A fill="0xffcc00" stroke="0x008000" stroke-width="1"/> <D fill="0xffcc00" stroke="0x008000" stroke-width="1"/> <O fill="0xffcc00" stroke="0x990066" stroke-width="1"/> </Unknown> <MEL number="1"> <A fill="0xd10000" stroke="0xf40000" stroke-width="1"/> <D fill="0x33" stroke="0xcc" stroke-width="1"/> <O fill="0xffcc00" stroke="0x008000" stroke-width="1"/> </MEL> </acColours> <trColours> <Unknown number="0"> <A fill="none" stroke="0xffcc00" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="150"/> <D fill="none" stroke="0xffcc00" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="150"/> <O fill="none" stroke="0x990066" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="150"/> </Unknown> <MEL number="1"> <A fill="none" stroke="0xf40000" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="150"/> <D fill="none" stroke="0xcc" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="150"/> <O fill="none" stroke="0xffcc00" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="150"/> </MEL> </trColours> <communities enable="0"/> ..........................many lines of data...............................
<nmts replicate="1" showPortables="1" tagfields="type,metric,starttime,endtime,maxtime,duration" visible="visible"> <download_queue enable="0"/>
    <locations name="Keilor East" download_noise_data="1" latitude="-37.73228" locid="3" longitude="144.86900" monitor_location_id="318" monitor_name="mel3"status="active" tagOrientation="SE" type="fixed" x="2857.2" y="23539.3"/>
    <locations name="Bulla" download_noise_data="1" latitude="-37.60686" locid="2" longitude="144.82314" monitor_location_id="320" monitor_name="mel2"status="active" tagOrientation="SE" type="fixed" x="-2247.9" y="41177.8"/>
</nmts>
 </config>
```

I , for example, only want to retrieve "locations" which are in "nmts" node.

Here is my code

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.myStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'myApp.model.myModel',
    storeId: 'myStore',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://webtrak.bksv.com/mel/configuration',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            rootProperty: 'nmts',
            record:'locations'
        }
    }
});
```

and here is my model

```
Ext.define('myApp.model.myModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'lat', type: 'float' },
            { name: 'lng', type: 'float' },
            { name: 'locid', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'monitor_location_id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'monitor_name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'status', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'tagOrientation', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'stationType', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'x', type: 'float' },
            { name: 'y', type: 'float' }

        ]
    }
});
```

You can see that my model only have a part of attributes from the data source.

and since the data source is on remote server I cannot test it in browsers, but when testing on devices, I cannot get any error feedback so that's the reason of making debugging impossible for me.

I am not sure whether I write the code in a right way, please point out my errors if there are any.

Thank you my friends.

Comment: hello~~~~~~echo~~~echo~~~~echo~~~~

Comment: Fanva, you can create a sencha fiddle with sample data then try whats happening. You can give a file name for url, like sample.xml

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir thx mate, I'll do it and let you know

Comment: Hi @OğuzÇelikdemir , do you have any ideas for solving the partially mapping model issue? thanks